# Trace of multi-index operator in path integral?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral

What is the formal definition of trace of an operator? Suppose I have an operator $L^{a_1a_2..}_{b_1b_2..}(x,y)$ in which $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s are discrete indices, and $x,y$ are continuous ones. So how can I trace this operator? Continuous indices appear in path integral frequently.

Answer (score 0):

For some integral operator $\mathcal{O}$ that acts on a function $f$ as
$$
(\mathcal{O}f)(x) = \int dy~\mathcal{O}(x,y) f(y)
$$
one can define
$$
\text{Tr } \mathcal{O} = \int dx~\mathcal{O}(x,x)
$$
In general for linear operators on Hilbert spaces, one generally has:
$$
\text{Tr } \mathcal{O} = \sum_X \langle X | \mathcal{O} | X\rangle
$$
where $|X \rangle$ is a complete orthonormal basis of the space. This can be generalized to "continuous bases", e.g. the position or momentum basis in QM.

Is this what you mean?